# Add custom options programmatically not working on product page

Tags: magento2, custom-options

When i execute follow code

```
    $options = [
    [
        'title' => 'drop_down option',
        'type' => 'drop_down',
        'is_require' => true,
        'sort_order' => 4,
        'values' => [
            [
                'title' => 'drop_down option 1',
                'price' => 10,
                'price_type' => 'fixed',
                'sku' => 'drop_down option 1 sku',
                'sort_order' => 1,
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'drop_down option 2',
                'price' => 20,
                'price_type' => 'fixed',
                'sku' => 'drop_down option 2 sku',
                'sort_order' => 2,
            ],
        ],
    ]
];

foreach ($options as $arrayOption) {
    $option = $this->objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::class)
        ->setProductId($_product->getId())
        ->setStoreId($_product->getStoreId())
        ->addData($arrayOption);
    $option->save();
    $_product->addOption($option);
    $_product->save();
}
```

- Custom Option not appear on product frontend page.
- When goto to product page from admin page and click save without any
  changing.
- Then goto frontend product page custom show up.

I want create option programmatically and should shown on front page without saving product from admin panel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try following way:

```
$_product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface')->getById(1, true);
$options = [
    [
        'title' => 'drop_down option',
        'type' => 'drop_down',
        'is_require' => true,
        'sort_order' => 4,
        'values' => [
            [
                'title' => 'drop_down option 1',
                'price' => 10,
                'price_type' => 'fixed',
                'sku' => 'drop_down option 1 sku',
                'sort_order' => 1,
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'drop_down option 2',
                'price' => 20,
                'price_type' => 'fixed',
                'sku' => 'drop_down option 2 sku',
                'sort_order' => 2,
            ],
        ],
    ]
];

foreach ($options as $arrayOption) {
    $option = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::class)
        ->setProductId($_product->getId())
        ->setStoreId($_product->getStoreId())
        ->addData($arrayOption);
    $option->save();
    $_product->addOption($option);
    $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface')->save($_product);
}
```

**Note:** Try to use DI instead of **$this->_objectManager**

Comment: its not working please see the image link https://ibb.co/diBFNd

Comment: @ArshadMuhammad I have tested M 2.3, it's working fine. Did you used exactly my code?

Comment: when i use your code separate its working but with my code its not working again same result showing.

Comment: For saving product use repository instead of product factory.

Comment: $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface')->save($_product);

Comment: For loading $_product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface')->getById(1, true);

Comment: It's not working when i upgrade magento 2.2.6

Comment: its not working.

Comment: @SohelRana Could you please help me on the question. 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293336/magento-2-override-for-product-custom-option-value-interface-and-model-file

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I added a custom drop_down option to a product programmatically. It appeared in the admin, but not on the frontend until saving the record again in the admin manually.

The issue was that `catalog_product_entity` did not have `has_options` set to 1. Setting that via `$product->setData('has_options',1)` fixes that issue.